# grouping and multiplying in select statement in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 columns ***product_id*** which contains id of different products(multiple orders with the same product id are also available), there is then ***ordered_quantity*** which contains how many products were ordered in a batch so I need to multiply them both. And at the end I want them in descending order.

SELECT
fk_product_id,
COUNT(fk_product_id) * ordered_quantity as total_quant_ordered
FROM `steel-time-347714.flex.order_items`
GROUP BY fk_product_id
ORDER BY total_quant_ordered DESC

I have the following error:- SELECT list expression references column ordered_quantity which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [3:26]

Comment: total_quant_ordered  should be in group by list as well

Comment: could you try putting order_qty in the group by clause and also provide sample table data to replicate this at my end?